# How can I wait for data from firebase database when using Object.keys(x).map() in react native?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to display information about users in a group in a list. I want to gather additional information about each member which is stored under `users/` in my database.

My code manages to gather information but only for the first member. To get the others members data to load, I need to navigate back to a different screen then go back.

Here is what I tried so far:

```js
//members object from group/id/members is passed to this function
//e.g. [{"uid":"abc","type":"admin"},{"uid":"def","type":"member"},{"uid":"ghi","type":"member"}]

getMembersData(members) {
  const membersData = {};

  Object.keys(members).map((key, i) => {
    const member = members[key];

    firebase.database().ref(`users/${member.uid}`).on('value', snap => {
      membersData[member.uid] = {
        'uid': member.uid,
        'username': snap.child('username').val(),
        'imageUrl': snap.child('imageUrl').val(),
        'type': member.type,
      };
    });
  });

  this.setState({ membersData });
}
```

In other words, when I navigate to the members screen, only the information for the first member is rendered when I map `this.state.membersData` in a View, until I back out from the screen and go back to it.

The code works fine if I cut out the firebase content. How can I fix this issue so that everything loads when I navigate to the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll want to call setState **inside the database callback** since the callback is **asynchronous** and won't be invoked until the data is finally available.

```
    firebase.database().ref(`users/${member.uid}`).on('value', snap => {
      membersData[member.uid] = {
        'uid': member.uid,
        'username': snap.child('username').val(),
        'imageUrl': snap.child('imageUrl').val(),
        'type': member.type,
      };
       this.setState(membersData);
    });
  });
```

There is no guarantee how long it will take to get the data, so your code should be ready to deal with the fact that it might take a while to arrive (or possibly never at all if there is no internet connection).

Answer (score 0):

You want to call `this.setState` once all of your database calls have finished. If you only need to download the data once, you can make use of [chaining Promises](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/keeping-our-promises-and-callbacks_76.html).

Because you are using `.map()`, you can achieve this by returning the Promise from database requests that use `.once('value')`. In the code below, the variable named `transformPromises` is the array of Promises produced by `.map()` and `.once('value')`. Once you have this array of promises, you can use `Promise.all(promiseArray).then(() => {...}` to wait for them all to resolve. In the code below, this is where we then call `this.setState()` to update the user interface.

Before calling `getMembersData()` it may be useful to show a [throbber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throbber) while loading the data.

```js
getMembersData(members) {
  const membersData = {};

  let transformPromises = Object.keys(members).map((key, i) => {
    const member = members[key];

    return firebase.database().ref(`users/${member.uid}`).once('value')
      .then(snap => {
        membersData[member.uid] = {
          'uid': member.uid,
          'username': snap.child('username').val(),
          'imageUrl': snap.child('imageUrl').val(),
          'type': member.type,
        };
      });
  });

  Promise.all(transformPromises)
    .then(() => {
      // all data was downloaded & added successfully.
      this.setState({ membersData });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      // handle error
      console.error(err)
    });
}
```

**Note:** Based on the shape of `members`, you could also iterate them using the following code:

```js
let transformPromises = members.map(member => {
  return firebase.database().ref(`users/${member.uid}`).once('value')
    .then(snap => {
      membersData[member.uid] = {
        'uid': member.uid,
        'username': snap.child('username').val(),
        'imageUrl': snap.child('imageUrl').val(),
        'type': member.type,
      };
    });
}
```